# How to reinstall Mac OS X built in Perl on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, install, perl

I updated to Mountain Lion 4 days ago and then realised that my perl scripts did not work any longer. So I installed ActivePerl 5.14 (newest version) because I thought that perl has been deleted. After installing ActivePerl though my programmes still did not work:

```
Warning message:
running command 'perl calc.pl' had status 2 
Can't locate Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm in @INC (@INC contains:    
/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 
/Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-
2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at calc.pl line 3.
```

In the terminal when I type perl -v it shows that it uses the newly installed ActivePerl. I used sudo clan -> install Excel::Writer::XLSX to install the missing module. However, it does not install it for 5.12 but for ActivePerl 5.14.

The own Mac OS X Perl seams to be installed here:

```
bash-3.2$ ls /Library/Perl/
5.10    5.12    Updates
bash-3.2$ ls /System/Library/Perl/
5.10    5.12    Extras  lib
bash-3.2$
```

There is also a version here:

```
bash-3.2$ ls /opt/local/lib/perl5/
5.12.4      site_perl   vendor_perl
```

I thought best is to delete the ActivePerl by running its uninstaller. I did that and also removed the 5.12.4 as well as the site_perl directory in /opt/local/lib/perl5.

Then I wanted to reinstall the XLSX::Writer module using cpan. I thought that it is then installed into the old perl directory. However running cpan now results in the following error:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo cpan
Can't locate strict.pm in @INC (@INC contains:    
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4/darwin-multi-2level 
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4 
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.4/darwin-multi-2level 
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.4 /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/darwin-multi-
2level /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4 /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl 
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level 
/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3 /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at 
/opt/local/bin/cpan line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/local/bin/cpan line 5.
```

I don't know what to do now. I think the best I can do is probably reinstalling Mac OS X's own Perl, how to do that?

Comment: Do you have macports installed? guessing from /opt/local/bin

Comment: yes I do. I just reinstalled xcode and the developer command line tools but still the same... I might just reinstall my whole system and restore some of my stuff via time machine. Wouldnt heart to have a clean system anyhow...

Comment: You need to decide what perl to use - Apple's, macports or activestate and then make sure only one appears in @INC - tell us which one then we can help

Comment: well, I want to use apples perl but to be able to use it I also need to install the XLSX.pm module for that version of perl. However, because of deleting some folders I cannot start cpan any longer... what you think is best to do?

Comment: Which directories did you delete?

Comment: thanks for your instant help: as mentioned in my question I deleted those two:  I did that and also removed the 5.12.4 as well as the site_perl directory in /opt/local/lib/perl5 PLUS run the activePerl uninstaller. So activePerl is I think gone. not sure what the /opt/ perl version is. Is it the one which comes from Xcode? I thought the one from xcode is installed into /Library/Perl and /System/Library/Perl

Comment: /opt perl is proaby macports - to remove that and I think from the @INC which is the important part - `sudo port uninstall perl5`

Answer (score 6):

I found on another website the following command

$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->notest(install => CPAN::Shell->r)'

This updated all my perl modules and all is back to normal.  Not sure why or what, but don't care that it is working now.

Comment: Here's [one source](http://www.kiffingish.com/2009/05/update-cpan-modules.html) of that command

Answer (score 0):

For various and sundry reasons upgrading the OS requires one to separately upgrade/reinstall MacPorts. The developers have actually created a pretty nice [Migration](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration) page that details the process necessary to get your ports environment working again after upgrading the OS.

Summarized, the steps you need to follow are:

1. Download and install new Xcode.
2. Make sure command line (gcc, make, etc.) tools are installed. From within the Xcode application go to Preferences->Downloads and install them.
3. Download the [MacPorts installer](http://www.macports.org/install.php) of choice for your OS version.
4. Install it.
5. Open your terminal of choice.
6. Run the command `port -qv installed > myports.txt`. This grabs a copy of all installed ports.
7. Uninstall all the ports: `sudo port -f uninstall installed`
8. Tidy up your play area: `sudo port clean all`
9. Go through the file `myports.txt` and reinstall the packages you actually want.

I actually sped up my reinstall process by editing the `myports.txt` file, such that it contained the names (and only the names) of the packages I wanted with one package per line, and running the following command

```
cat myports.txt | xargs -n1 port install
```

What this does is go through that file and execute the command `port install line` for every line in the file. It is a useless use of cat, butwho cares, it's easier to read.